# Silverlight control comes at the top

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, silverlight, colorbox

I have a silverlight control that opens up on a web page. But at the same time, on some user action, a jquery colorbox also opens. That colorbox is not shown as it comes behind the silverlight. Is there any way to change the z-index of silverlight component?

Comment: Potentially with combinations of the `z-index` and `position` css properties. What do you have so far?

Comment: That does not work. I saw something like doing $('object').attr("wmode", "transparent"); but that too didnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your Silverlight HTML parameters has its `windowless` mode set to `true`.

HTML Syntax:

```
<object ...>
  <param name="windowless" value="bool"/>
  ...
</object>
```

Or if you're leveraging Silverlight.js

```
Silverlight.CreateObject(,,,{windowless:'bool'});
-or-
Silverlight.CreateObjectEx({properties:{windowless:'bool'}});
```

By default, `windowless` is set to `false`. Basically, when `false`, Silverlight uses its own super-imposed "window" to perform rendering. In this state, it will *always* appear above *all* HTML content as it's not actually using the browser to render. In this state, the Silverlight plugin will essentially ignore the browser/CSS z-index as it's no longer applicable.

When `windowless` is set to true, it ties into the browser's rendering system which lets you layer HTML content (including iframes and jquery color boxes) above it. There are a few downsides to running `windowless`, but most likely you won't be affected much. In this state, you'll be able to leverage the typical z-index ordering within the browser/CSS.

Here's the MSDN article on it along with the pros/cons and the code snippets I posted above: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838156%28VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help but I dont have access to the silverlight code and have xap file only. How can I modify the attribute?

Comment: @Ankit It's set on the HTML page hosting the Silverlight control, not _in_ the Silverlight code/XAP so you're in luck!